# How to initialize DateTimePicker for elements added to the DOM on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need to initialize a [Bootstrap-DateTimePicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for inputs using jquery class-selector for elements that were created on the fly.

Typically, I would initialize the datetime picker for elements that were created when page is ready like so

```
$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({
     format: 'D/M/YYYY',
     useCurrent: false
});
```

But now I need to also apply the same thing on elements that were created on the dynamically. To get that to work, I did the following hack

```
$(document).on('focus', '.date-picker', function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        format: 'D/M/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false
    });
});
```

The above code work only when you focus on the input which then it initialize the date time picker.

The issue with the above code, is that when an input has a "incorrectly formatted" default value, the format does not change. In another word, when the page is loaded the input does not have the DateTime bounded to it.

I tried to call the `focus()`  event on page load, but that does not seems to be working either. This is what I tried

```
$(document).on('focus', '.date-picker', function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        format: 'D/M/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false
    });
}).focus();
```

How can I initialize the datetimepicker for predefined elements and elements that were dynamically created after page load?

I created the following fiddle to show how the datetime is not initialized on page load https://jsfiddle.net/516zsh7b/510/

Comment: Your code is not run until you set focus to an element (only one can have focus at a time).

Comment: That explains why `.focus()` isn't working. What is the work around for this?

Comment: Call your code outside an event (or may be an 'input' event).

Comment: @PoulBak can you please explain?

Comment: @MikeA he means use [`input`](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-input) instead of `focus`.

Comment: When you have created and added your element, call your code on each added element.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu unless I misunderstood your recommendation it isn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/516zsh7b/511/

Comment: I haven't tested it. If it doesn't work, use `click tap keyup mouseup`. They all bubble (so can be used with delegation) and they should cover all input interactions. The correct way of doing it for your case is by binding on `focus`, on the element, after you create it dynamically. In the success callback of whatever is adding it to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way would be to know how/when you add these new elements and add the logic there...

If you really need a reactive way to run a piece of JS code when an element is added to DOM, you could try mutation observers (not the best for performance):
http://ryanmorr.com/using-mutation-observers-to-watch-for-element-availability/